# Ender 5 Pro print quality issue

Tags: print-quality, extrusion, underextrusion, creality-ender-5

I got my 3D printer from Creality 1 day ago. My dog off the SD card came perfectly, Benchy was also printed almost flawlessly. I used standard Benchy settings on all my prints.

Now I tried making a [mask](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4225667) and it failed mid-print. When I saw it failing I stopped the print.

What do you guys think is the cause of this?

I printed with the following settings:

- I use PLA 50 °C bed and 200 °C hot end
- Resolution: 0.20 mm
- Infill: 20 %
- 3 walls with a line width of 0.4 mm each
- 50 mm/s first time i printed it and 40 mm/s second time.
- Combing OFF
- Retraction enabled
- Retraction distance:6 mm
- 25 mm/s all retraction speeds
- retraction extra prime amount 0
- retraction minimum travel 1.5
- maximum retraction count 100

[image: print]

[image: benchy]

---

I printed the mask again. this time I changed Z Seam alignment in Cura from user specified to random. It improved it a bit but it was not a successful print.
[image: second mask]

Comment: What about trying to print another benchy? That way we can see if it's an issue with the printer.

Comment: i will do it tomorrow. Anyway, this mask was printed right after the benchy. The only problem on the benchy is like a line on the left side and some ghosting. I'll post a picture soon.

Comment: What speed? Looks like printing too fast for the hotend to keep up.

Comment: Is the filament entangled at some point?

Comment: no. filament seems alright. I am using the filament that came in the box with the printer.

Comment: Did you try to reduce the 6 mm of retraction down to 3 mm?

Comment: @Wolfram: 3 mm retraction is not sufficient for a bowden, and there's no good reason the standard appropriate amount of retraction for this machine should cause the problem the OP is seeing.

Comment: Not sure if OP is still around, but if so: do you perhaps have coasting enabled? It's a Cura antifeature that could lead to this.

Answer (score 1):

I was told to not even bother using the white filament which came with the Ender 5 as it was very low quality. I used an orange filament from Hatchbox and, once I have learned to adjust my settings (I found it works better at 210-215 °C), it seems to be great.

Comment: Yeah, the white filament that came with my Ender 3 pro was of questionable quality, though I was eventually able to use it after some experimentation. I've had much easier success with every other filament since. It's weird that they wouldn't just include a mini roll of their quality PLA with their printers, it would be a great help to people who are new to printing

Comment: Very true. New filament 206 °C, level bed thicker paper, infill: 100 % and watch if filament is fed properly.